# VM: Error Starting Domain: USB Device Not Found

Tags: systemd, filesystems, libvirt

I have a working VM that will not load unexpectedly.  Using virt-manager in CentOS7

Error is

```
Error Starting Domain: internal error: Did not find USB device 05ac:12a8
```

I see USB device `05ac:12a8` in the QEMU GUI.

I do not know what USB device this would be on the server since this is virtualization.

[image: VMerror]

Here are the details of the error:

```
Error starting domain: internal error: Did not find USB device 05ac:12a8

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 125, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/libvirtobject.py", line 82, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1506, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1080, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: internal error: Did not find USB device 05ac:12a8
```

`libvirtd` status also confirms the device isn't found:

```
[orca@orcacomputers ~]$ systemctl status libvirtd -l
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-09-22 15:44:22 PDT; 12min ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           https://libvirt.org
 Main PID: 2419 (libvirtd)
    Tasks: 17 (limit: 32768)
   Memory: 23.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
           └─2419 /usr/sbin/libvirtd

Sep 22 15:44:23 orcacomputers libvirtd[2419]: 2021-09-22 22:44:23.269+0000: 2523: error : storageDriverAutostartCallback:209 : internal error: Failed to autostart storage pool 'CentOS': cannot open directory '/mnt/raid5/VM/CentOS': No such file or directory
Sep 22 15:44:23 orcacomputers libvirtd[2419]: 2021-09-22 22:44:23.295+0000: 2523: error : virUSBDeviceFindByVendor:229 : internal error: Did not find USB device 05ac:12a8
Sep 22 15:44:23 orcacomputers libvirtd[2419]: 2021-09-22 22:44:23.386+0000: 2523: warning : virHostdevReAttachUSBDevices:1922 : Unable to find device 000.000 in list of active USB devices
Sep 22 15:44:23 orcacomputers libvirtd[2419]: 2021-09-22 22:44:23.386+0000: 2523: warning : virHostdevReAttachUSBDevices:1922 : Unable to find device 000.000 in list of active USB devices
Sep 22 15:44:23 orcacomputers libvirtd[2419]: 2021-09-22 22:44:23.386+0000: 2523: warning : virHostdevReAttachUSBDevices:1922 : Unable to find device 000.000 in list of active USB devices
Sep 22 15:44:23 orcacomputers libvirtd[2419]: 2021-09-22 22:44:23.386+0000: 2523: error : qemuAutostartDomain:258 : internal error: Failed to autostart VM 'Debian': internal error: Did not find USB device 05ac:12a8
Sep 22 15:45:18 orcacomputers libvirtd[2419]: 2021-09-22 22:45:18.706+0000: 2473: error : virUSBDeviceFindByVendor:229 : internal error: Did not find USB device 05ac:12a8
Sep 22 15:45:18 orcacomputers libvirtd[2419]: 2021-09-22 22:45:18.706+0000: 2473: warning : virHostdevReAttachUSBDevices:1922 : Unable to find device 000.000 in list of active USB devices
Sep 22 15:45:18 orcacomputers libvirtd[2419]: 2021-09-22 22:45:18.706+0000: 2473: warning : virHostdevReAttachUSBDevices:1922 : Unable to find device 000.000 in list of active USB devices
Sep 22 15:45:18 orcacomputers libvirtd[2419]: 2021-09-22 22:45:18.706+0000: 2473: warning : virHostdevReAttachUSBDevices:1922 : Unable to find device 000.000 in list of active USB devices
```

Answer (score 1):

In general terms:

`05ac:12a8` is the identifier of a USB bus. They aren't available by default, they have to be added manually. Just deleting the offending device should allow the VM to boot. If you don't want to allow the VM to access USB devices, you can delete all three as well.

Before you do it, it's as usual advisable to backup the VM. The default save path is `/var/lib/libvirt/images`, extension is `.qcow`. I'd also recommend checking `/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/save` - if the machine is in saved state, you will find here a file with matching name but extension `.save`. If deleting the USB bus causes problems, current status quo is easy to restore just by copying the file(s) back to original location(s).

***In this specific case:***

There's also message

`cannot open directory '/mnt/raid5/VM/CentOS'`

This could refer to actual USB storage that was connected to that USB bus when the VM was created. I obviously have no way of knowing, you just have to test. So please do backup the files before changing anything.